# Ajax in a template file to show the value of session variable

Tags: 7, ajax

I have a webform in my node.tpl which action points to hook_menu url of a module.

When the form submit happens, it compiles the form data in the custom module and stores the response value in a session variable; then, the page is reloaded and the session variable printed in the node template.

I want to show the same session variable without reloading the page.

Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: Are you using custom code or using default webform ajax functionality?

Comment: I am using custom form in template

Comment: Can you please share your code then to get a better understanding?